# angular2-bootstrap-pagination move to higher level

Tags: angular, pagination, angular2-directives

I've got error about Angular2 bootstrap module, i'm using the same module in diffreent pages.

When i moved the module to a higher level, i've got this error :

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'totalItems' since it isn't a known property of 'ng-pagination'.
```

Answer (score 1):

the imports for where you use it may `import` the directives needed for the module. Can you see any imports that need to be moved higher as well?

Comment: when I use this Directive in two modules "import { PaginationDirective } from 'angular2-bootstrap-pagination/directives/pagination.directive';" I get the following error : Error: Type PaginationDirective is part of the declarations of 2 modules: DevicesModule and Users_ManagementModule! Please consider moving PaginationDirective to a higher module that imports DevicesModule and Users_ManagementModule

Comment: Don't import the directive twice though, only once where it is used.

Comment: But i need it in both Users_ManagementModule and DevicesModule

Comment: I need some more information like what is in what? is `Users_ManagementModule` in `DevicesModule `, or the other way around? Or are they not contained in eachother?

Comment: They are not contained in each others

Comment: Okay remove the import directive from both and put it in their direct parent module, probably AppModule

Comment: Here is the architecture : http://ge.tt/9GL0NTl2
I did it, but the atributes are not known

Comment: Okay so your root module is probably `AppModule` or something similiar try including the directive in there perhaps

Comment: I did, but parameters like totalItems and othrrs are not known as a property.